# R - Assign name to dataframe for every loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, paste

I have a loop that has six iterations:

```
Perc <- c(0.99,0.90,0.80,0.70,0.60,0.50)

for(x in 1:length(Perc))
{
}
```

Each loop creates a dataframe called '`Data`'

I need to name each dataframe `Data_0.99, Data_0.90, Data_0.80`........and so on so I can refer back to them later in the code.

I figured this would do it `paste("Data_",Perc[x],sep = "") <- Data`

However I get the below error:

```
Error in paste("Data_", Perc[x], sep = "") <- Data : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

If anyone could point me in the direction of how to name each dataframe as the loop creates it that would be fantastic.

Also happy to add more information, code data if that will help!

Comment: This has been answered many times already. Just use a list.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, could you point me in the direction of an example?

Comment: I have closed your question and you can find a link to an example at the top now.